Network bandwidth on VM.Standard.E2.1.Micro (oracle cloud)
In oracle cloud:

When I setup a VM.Standard.E2.1.Micro (Always Free eligible) it says: 0.48 Gbps Network bandwidth
When I setup a VM.Standard.A1.Flex (Always Free eligible) with 4 OCPU it says: 4 Gbps Network bandwidth

When I then run the VM, I get:

VM.Standard.E2.1.Micro: 0.05 Gbps  (i.e. 10 times less than expected)
VM.Standard.A1.Flex: 4 Gbps

Given I am getting the advertised speed on the A1, I was expecting to get the advertised speed on the E2.1.Micro.
Is the advertised speed wrong, or am I doing something wrong?
The 2 VPS are on the same subnet.
thanks for any insights!

According to
https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/FreeTier/freetier_topic-Always_Free_Resources.htm
The internal network speed is 0.48Gbps but external is only 50Mbps
